# Standalone Matlab program

Tags: matlab

I have heard that it is possible to make standalone programs using Matlab compiler. 
It is good but I doubt that if someone can use the commands in the tool boxes and make a standalone program out of them otherwise one could make a program using optimization tool box and distribute it, then no body would pay for such a too box. Am I right? Is it possible to use the features available in tool boxes to make a standalone program in Matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certain features in toolboxes which are not supported by MATLAB Compiler. These mainly include  GUIs provided with the toolboxes, such as `imtool`, `cftool`, `systemIdentification`, `pidTuner`, etc... and things the Compiler itself, or code-generation tools such as MATLAB Coder. For an exhaustive list, see [Support for MATLAB and Toolboxes](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/compiler/supported/compiler_support.html) on the MathWorks web site.

Note that for the end user to run the compiled MATLAB application, he first needs to install the MCR (MATLAB Component Runtime) on his machine. This is essentially a "headless" version of MATLAB which can only be called by the compiled application, and is freely distributable to end users by the person who has a license for MATLAB Compiler.